# A better variable naming system?

Tags: perl, foreach

A newbie to programming. The task is to extract a particular data from a string and I chose to write the code as follows -

```
while ($line =<IN>) {
    chomp $line;
    @tmp=(split /\t/, $line); 
    next if ($tmp[0] !~ /ch/); 
    @tgt1=@tmp[8..11];
    @tgt2=@tmp[12..14];
    @tgt3=@tmp[15..17];
    @tgt4=@tmp[18..21];
    foreach (1..4) {
            print @tgt($_), "\n";
            }
```

I thought `@tgt($_)` would be interpreted as `@tgt1, @tgt2, @tgt3, @tgt4` but I still get the error message that `@tgt` is a global symbol (@tgt1, @tgt2, @tgt3, @tgt4` have been declared).

Q1. Did I misunderstand foreach loop?

Q2. Why couldn't perl see `@tgt($_)` as @tgt1, @tgt2 ..etc?

Q2. From the experience this is probably a bad way to name variables. What would be a preferred way to name variables that have similar features?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Sorry, Ikegami, I did use strict and warnings, but I only pasted part of the code that I think is relevant (as suggested by the warnings and errors).

Comment: @BChen - I'm surprised that `@tgt($_)` even compiled :)

Comment: @B Chen, One of the reasons to use `use strict;` is to be forced to declare variables so they are properly scoped. You seem to have missed the point since your variables are not properly scoped. The scope of variables should be limited to where the variable is needed (within reason), which is to say the variables should be declared in the loop.

Comment: @ikegame, Right. Now I remember I did read it somewhere that variables should be limited to where they are needed. Will learn to keep them in the right loops. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> - Q2. Why couldn't perl see @tgt($_) as @tgt1, @tgt2 ..etc?
> - Q2. From the experience this is probably a bad way to name variables. What would be a preferred way to name variables that have similar features?

I'll asnswer both together.

`@tgt($_)` does NOT mean what you hope it means

- First off, it's an invalid syntax (you can't use () after an array name, perl interpeter will produce a compile error).
- What you're trying to do is access distinct variables by accessing a variable via an expression resulting in its name (aka [symbolic references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Symbolic-references)). This IS possible to do; but is typically a bad idea and poor-style Perl (as in, you CAN but you SHOULD NOT do it, without a very very good reason).
- To access element $_ the way you tried, you use `@{"tgt$_"}` syntax. But I repeat - **Do Not Do That**, even if you can.
- **A correct idiomatic solution**: use an array of arrayrefs, with your 1-4 (or rather 0-3) indexing the outer array:

  ```
   # Old bad code: @tgt1=@tmp[8..11];

   # New correct code:
   $tgt[0]=[ @tmp[8..11] ]; # [] creates an array reference from a list.
   # etc... repeat 4 times - you can even do it in a smart loop later.
  ```

  What this does is, it stores a reference to an array slice into a zeroth element of a single `@tgt` array.

  At the end, `@tgt` array has 4 elements , each an array reference to an array containing one of the slices.

---

> - Q1. Did I misunderstand foreach loop?

Your foreach loop (as opposed to its contents - see above) was correct, with one style caveat - again, while you CAN use a default `$_` variable, you should almost never use it, instead always use named variables for readability.

You print the abovementioned array of arrayrefs as follows (ask separately if any of the syntax is unclear - this is a mid-level data structure handling, not for beginners):

```
foreach my $index (0..3) { 
    print join(",", @{ $tgt[$index]}) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Excellent explanation for beginners !! (you should try to write a book/tutorial of sort !!) I did read a bit about reference but have not gotten my head around it to be useful for my coding.

Comment: @BChen - [this is my book](http://stackoverflow.com/users/119280/dvk?tab=answers&sort=votes) :) And thank you for kind words. Stick around, Perl is super powerful, the trick is knowing when NOT to abuse its power at the cost of producing unreadable code for no noticeable gain. There are usually many ways of doing things, and some are better suited for different goals.